# VirtualBox Windows 10 Guest no keyboard on Start Menu

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox

Experiencing odd behavior only in my Windows 10 Guest.
When I click the start menu, no keyboard output goes to the VM.
I can still click on applications with the mouse.
I've also seen this in the VPN creation screen.

I have a Windows 7 VM and have not had this happen.

I have the latest version of VirtualBox and Extensions.
I've also tried switching to full screen mode and enabling/disabling Auto Capture Keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem eventually went away after updates to VirtualBox and Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this site to ask and answer things about [elementary OS](https://elementary.io). If you have problem with Windows you can ask at [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com) where you can get helped by volunteers and as well as Microsoft support agents.
About your question, I think installation of [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.0/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.0.vbox-extpack) is the solution to your problem.